# Difference between “operator” and "statement" in programming

Tags: differences, programming

To describe the same language units in computer programs I came across words such as: "operator" and "statement". Also my dictionary gives these words as synonyms.

**Question:** what is the difference and what is better to use in programming? Or is it not important? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a feeling that the exact difference between the terms will vary depending on the programming language being used. So it's not really an English language question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belong on a computing-related site.

Comment: @KillingTime Thank you for your opinion!

Comment: @Hot Licks After reading the answer, I agree with your decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to be 100% sure without more information from you, but either you or your sources are incorrect. An "operator" is never the same as a statement.

An operator is a symbol that acts like a function. In most (all?) languages, it can operate on one, two, or three values. This is not unique to computer science; the idea of an operator comes from mathematics, where an operator represents a mapping from one space to another.

On the other hand, a statement is the smallest unit of an imperative language that expresses some action to be taken out.

An operator without values doesn't do anything, so an operator cannot be a statement.

An operator with the appropriate number of values is known as an expression, but still may not be a statement, if it doesn't do anything.

For instance

```
i++;
```

is a statement, because it assigns a value to `i`. However

```
i + j;
```

is not a statement as it doesn't perform an action. Some languages would flag this as an error. Other languages will remove this during compilations. Others still will perform the operation and then discard the value.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! Now I understand the difference between these words.

Comment: The definition here is not totally correct.
**An operator is not executable by itself**, for example `i+j;` or `i++;` are not operators, the operators are `+` and `++`. **They are actually both statements, because they are executable** (even if one of them has no side effects). Note that operators are not limited to symbols, for example `a || b` and `a or b` are both quite common (`||` and `or` are both operators).

Comment: The number of arguments an operator (also known as operands) requires, is known as "operator arity". I.e.`!x` has an arity of 1 (aka unary operator), `x || y` an arity of 2 (aka binary operator), `x ? y :z` has 3 and is known as a ternary operator (note that some languages call the `x ? y : z` operator "the ternary operator" which is not wrong, but a bit of an oversight). Theoretically, there could be higher arity operators, but it's not common to my knowledge.